Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container - no such file or directory: unknown
I am using WSL on window to code.
I run docker-compose up and it will build Dockerfile, but I got this error
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/app/start.sh": stat /app/start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
but the start.sh file already there
My entire capture VSCode
I tried add:
RUN chmod +x start.sh
RUN ls

but it does not working, and the RUN ls is not log anything.
Pls help!

Rather than a screenshot of your Dockerfile please include the file contents itself (or a stripped down version that can be used to replicate the error). It would also be helpful to see your docker-compose.yml.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A stripped down version of the Dockerfile in your screenshot:
FROM alpine:3.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY start.sh ./start.sh

RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD [ "/app/main" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/start.sh" ]

That builds fine.
Do you have any volumes mounted via your docker-compose.yml? I suspect that this file is not available at run time because it's being occluded by a volume mount. If you could add your docker-compose.yml it'd help to understand what's going wrong.
